# Importing all needed modules in one main file that has all needed libraries for modules imported

Tags: python, class, module, libraries

I for example i have 2 files, mother.py and child.py,
child.py is module that is imported in mother.py

Code in mother.py is:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from modules.child import LoginWindow

root = Tk()
window = LoginWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Code in child.py is:

```
class LoginWindow:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.content = ttk.Frame(self.master, padding=(20,30,20,30))
```

And when i do this it give me an error that says that `tkk` ( in last line of child.py ) is not defined but it is defined in mother.py ( line 2 ) why is not this working and what is the best way to make something like this work

Comment: Imports don't get passed down like that. You need to move the ttk import into child.py. If imports were injected from the parent code would be much less readable, and only work if imported from certain places (which complicates testing and reuse).

Comment: add `from tkinter import ttk` to child.py

Comment: tnx guys just one more thing, if i import all ( not just one class like now ) from child.py with `from tkinter import ttk` in it and i still have `from tkinter import ttk` in mother.py would that be like duplicating effect, is that the right way

Comment: @Šime no, it won't be loaded twice - Python will just look it up in a dictionary the second time.

Comment: thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An import in Python isn't like an "include" in other languages. The entire module is contained inside an object named after the module you imported. So, when you do this:

```
from modules.child import LoginWindow
```

The entire module is contained inside the object/variable `LoginWindow`. The "child" module in this case cannot see what variables are defined inside the module that imported it.

In the example in your question, you want to move:

```
from tkinter import ttk
```

To `child.py`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i thought that import is something like `include` in php, guess there is no such a thing in python?

Comment: I figured you were coming from PHP :) No problem! No, there's nothing similar in Python. However, if you `import my_module`, and can access variables and functions from `my_module` via `my_module.my_var` or `my_module.my_func()`.